# Conflict between PyQt5 and datetime.datetime.strptime

Tags: python, datetime, pyqt5

So I was writing a tool that would read time from file using graphical user interface based on python 3.52 and Qt5. The minimal operation

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('Tue', '%a')
```

works in an isolated environment, giving output "1900-01-01 00:00:00". However, when I run the following minimal example

```
import sys
import datetime as datetime

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    print(datetime.datetime.strptime('Tue', '%a'))
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    print(datetime.datetime.strptime('Tue', '%a'))
    #sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I get the output

```
1900-01-01 00:00:00
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/gui/testfile.py", line 11, in <module>
print(datetime.datetime.strptime('Tue', '%a'))
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 510, in _strptime_datetime
tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 343, in _strptime
(data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Tue' does not match format '%a'
```

So, the first call to the *strptime* routine works fine, but after the *QApplication* class is created, it does not work any more. Note that further using *QApplication* to construct the GUI and do a lot of complicated things with it works fine. The only thing that does not work currently is *strptime*

Any idea what goes wrong?

Comment: I've tried your script and I can't reproduce, it doesn't crash here (3.5.1 x64,QT_VERSION_STR=5.7.0, PYQT_VERSION_STR=5.7, win7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem: after calling the QtWidget, the

`print(datetime.datetime.strptime('Tue', '%a'))`

results in an error.

If I execute after QtWidget

`print(datetime.datetime.strptime('Die', '%a'))`
this works.

I am located in Switzerland, so *Die* in German is equivalent to *Tue*.

It seems that Qt somehow has an influence on the region settings as %A and %a evaluates the local weekday's name([Datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)). Maybe a Qt expert can explain more in detail, what is ongoing.

Comment: It probably calls [`setlocale(LC_ALL, '')`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setlocale) or equivalent at some point during its initialization

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the nice answer by Patrick, I have now found a way to undo the localization enforced by QT

```
import sys
import datetime as datetime
import locale

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

## Start the QT window
print(datetime.datetime.strptime('Tue', '%a'))
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "en_GB.utf8")
print(datetime.datetime.strptime('Tue', '%a'))
#sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Note that this will only work if the `en_GB.utf8` locale is installed on the os, otherwise it will raise an exception. The [default on startup of a program](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setlocale) is the `C` locale, so to be portable you might want to use that.

Comment: This fix did the trick while trying to call `strptime` from a Python3 Jupyter notebook after calling the Qt GUI module (`%gui qt`). Thanks for suggesting this answer!